# How to calculate the Profit/Loss using Pandas Pivot Table for every BUY and SELL in rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I need to calculate the profit/Loss for every trading symbol pair (BUY Order, SELL Order) which are in each rows. Please find below my dataframe:

[image]

Computation Logic:

1. Every BROKERCODE will have BUY and SELL rows related to Trading Symbols and not necessarily as pairs
2. Sometimes a BROKERCODE can have either a BUY or a SELL row related to a particular Trading symbol (Row 8, 11)
3. If we find a pair of BUY & SELL for a particular trading symbol then we can find the Profit or Loss by subtracting (ORD_AMT(SELL) - ORD_AMT(BUY))
4. If we do not find a pair for trading symbol, then we don't compute PNL for such a row
5. If the QTY_FILLED is '0', we can ignore such rows

I tried with Pandas PIVOT_TABLE, however could not successfully achieve the required logic. Any code snippets in this regard will be of great help.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: Does `ORDERID` always increase with time?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the expected result for the given sample data (and an explanation of how that is derived).

Comment: @Srinivas it would be much easier if you posted the data in the form of text or a table (the screenshot cannot be copied and reproduced).